# How to make a single line DEBUG(x) macro to contain multi-line code segment "x" properly? Is it possible? C language

Tags: c, debugging, macros

Using a function instead of a macro might be a better solution but just wanted to ask.

Assume some code segment can be turned ON and OFF by using the implementation below:

```
/* config.h file */
#define DEBUG_STATUS_function_a ENABLED


/* Some.c file */
    
void function_a() {
    #if DEBUG_STATUS_function_a == ENABLED
        printf("You are in function_a()\n");
    #endif
        
    ... /* ACTUAL CODE */
    return;
```

What I would like to do is to use the macro in the way below:

```
#define DEBUG_function_a(code_segment, DEBUG_STATUS_function_a)     #if DEBUG_STATUS_function_a == ENABLED
                                                                        code_segment
                                                                    #endif
```

Actual example:

```
/* config.h file */ 
#define DEBUG_STATUS_function_a ENABLED
#define DEBUG_function_a(printf("You are in function_a()\n");, DEBUG_STATUS_function_a)     #if DEBUG_STATUS_function_a == ENABLED
                                                                                                printf("You are in function_a()\n");
                                                                                            #endif

/* Some.c file */
    
void function_a() {
    DEBUG_function_a(printf("You are in function_a()\n");,DEBUG_STATUS_function_a)

    ... /* REST OF CODE */
    return;
```

This does not look like the best practice but still, what is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```c
#define DEBUGF(debug, message) do { \
                                   if (debug) { \
                                       printf message; \
                                   } \
                               } while(0)

#define DEBUG_STATUS_function_a 1

...

// later in some function
DEBUGF(DEBUG_STATUS_function_a, ("Some message %d\r\n", 10));
DEBUGF(DEBUG_STATUS_function_a, ("Some other message\r\n"));
```

If you use optimizations, the construct `if (0) {}` will be optimized out if you disable the `DEBUG_STATUS_function_a` define.

`do { ... } while(0)` is helper to make C happy. The macro will behave like a regular function in most cases.

If you don't want to mess with variadic macros, `message` must always contain parenthesis, but it enables you to use formatting.

You can extend this by using [Variadic Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) but it is heavily compiler specific to be fully functional and you don't specify C standard nor compiler you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer is quite informative.